# Reverse Engineering Tool for spring and hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven-2, reverse-engineering

I have java web application code mostly annotation base. Application uses Spring core, Spring MVC, Spring security, hiberanate and  jsp . It uses maven to build the project and consist of multiple maven projects.
There is no documentation at all for the code. 
Can you suggest me any open source or commercial tool to analyse application flow and data flow.

It also fine, If can create flow from deployed application in JBoss. I mean from ear.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). It usually used for performance instrumentation, but since it also builds call-hierarchies you should be able to use it for your purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Start up in debug mode, set a break point at beginning and step through.  Anlayzing program flow is not reverse engineering btw.